# Why find triangles in graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Given a graph, there are numerous algorithms out there to find a set of 3 vertices such that a triangle exists, but why is this topic studied? What are the applications? The advantages? The problems encountered?

Comment: In 3-connected cubic graphs you can replace triangles by single points...

Comment: I don't know much about graph theory, but triangularizing a plane graph can be useful for finding a coloring, which can be used to solve [interesting problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Art_gallery_problem).

Comment: One example -- a complex connection of gears.  If there is a triangle, or any odd circuit, the network of gears will fail. 

As a social network test, if there are no triangles in a large social network, it is unbelievable.